# jquery datatable provide a date function in form of milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

to all I have written the code for updating the task ownerid by the lookup field owner selection the tasks are shown by the given datepicker value under the query in controller.Now I struggle here my code is update the ownerid perfectly but the activtitydate column in the jquery datatable column is provide the date in millisecond format so I want how to change this into mm/dd/yyyy format.

my controller:

```
//Remote function using updated the owner of the task
public class TaskOwnerUpdate {

    public String dueDate { get; set; }
    public Set<Id> selectedTaskIdSet {get; set;}
    String ownerIdValue {get; set;}
    String selectedColumnValue {get; set;}
    public static List<Task> taskList { get; set;}
    public TaskOwnerUpdate() { } // empty constructor
    public List<Task>selectedtaskList {get; set;}

    public Task getOwnerIdTask() {

        return [SELECT  OwnerId FROM TASK LIMIT 1];
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static List<Task> getTask (String dueDate) {

        system.debug('dueDate value is------>'+dueDate);
        List<String> stList = dueDate.split('"');
        system.debug('stList value---->'+stList);
        List<String>s1 = stList[0].split(',');
        system.debug('stList[0] value is---->'+stList[0]);
        system.debug('stList[1] value is---->'+stList[1]);
        List<String> splitList = stList[1].split('/');
        system.debug('splitList value is---->'+splitList);
        String dueDate1 = splitList[2]+'-'+splitList[0]+'-'+splitList[1]; 
        taskList = [SELECT Id, Subject, Priority, Status, ActivityDate, Owner.Name, OwnerId
                   FROM Task WHERE ActivityDate >= :Date.valueOf(dueDate1)];
        system.debug('taskList- value is------>'+taskList);
        return taskList;        

    }

    @RemoteAction 
    public static List<Task> updateTask(String ownerIdValue, String selectedColumnValue ) {

        system.debug('OwnerId value is----->'+ownerIdValue);
        system.debug('selectedColumnValue value is---->'+selectedColumnValue);

        List<Task> updatedTaskList = new List<Task>();


        Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<String> deserializeStringList = (List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(selectedColumnValue, List<String>.class);

        system.debug('deserializeStringList value>>>>'+deserializeStringList);

        for (String strRecord : deserializeStringList) {

            Task taskRecord = new Task();
            taskRecord.Id = Id.valueOf(strRecord);
            taskRecord.OwnerId = Id.valueOf(ownerIdValue);
            updatedTaskList.add(taskRecord);
        } 

        if (updatedTaskList.size() > 0) {
            Update updatedTaskList;
        }
         return updatedTaskList;

    }

}
```

and my page:

```js
<apex:page controller="TaskOwnerUpdate">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"/>

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Task Ownership Update"/>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Tasks">
 <!---- Section to draw search field for account-------> 
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Tasks" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:inputText value="{!dueDate}" size="10" id="demo" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false)">dueDate</apex:inputText>
                <apex:inputField value="{!OwnerIdTask.OwnerId}" id="owner"></apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <button onclick="getTask();return false;">Get Task</button>            
                <button id="button">Update</button>     
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:actionFunction name="callaction" oncomplete="getTask()" reRender="output"/>
    
     <!-- result section for showing matching accounts ------->
        <apex:outputPanel id="output">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Matching Tasks !" columns="1">
            <!-- 
            Created Empty table using the CSS styles of visualforce pageBlockTable 
            This gives same look and feel ------>
            
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="searchResults" class="list ">
                    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
                    <thead class="rich-table-thead">
                        <tr class="headerRow ">
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Select</th> 
                            <!--<th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Id</th>---->
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Subject</th>
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Priority</th>
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Status</th>
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">ActivityDate</th>
                            <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">OwnerName</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <!-- table body left empty for populating via row template using jquery-------> 
                    <tbody />
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>  
        
    <script id="resultTableRowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " class="dataRow even  first">
            <td class="datacel">${Select}<input type = "checkbox" id="${Id}"/></td>
            <!---<td class="Idvalue">${Id}</td>------>
            <td class="datacell">${Subject}</td>
            <td class="dataCell">${Priority}</td>
            <td class="dataCell">${Status}</td>
            <td class="datecell">${ActivityDate}</td>
            <td class="datacell">${Owner.Name}</td>      
        </tr>
    </script>
    
  </apex:pageBlock> 
                 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // if you are inside some component
        // use jquery nonConflict
        // var t$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log("check call correct");
        //var dt = Date.new Instance(document.getElementById('datecell'));
        //console.log('dt value', dt);
        function getTask() {
        
            var dueDate = $('[id$=":demo"]').val();//$('#demo').val();
            console.log("check data",dueDate);
            // clear previous results, if any
            $("#searchResults tbody").html('');
            
            // The Spring-11 gift from force.com. Javascript remoting fires here
            // Please note "abhinav" if my org wide namespace prefix
            // testremotingcontroller is the Apex controller
            // searchAccounts is Apex Controller method demarcated with @RemoteAction annotation.
            // DEPRECATED -     abhinav.testremotingcontroller.searchAccounts( accountName, ...) 
            // NEW - summer'12 approach for calling'
            
            dueDate = JSON.stringify(dueDate);
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.TaskOwnerUpdate.getTask}',
                           dueDate, function(result, event){  
                           console.log("due date",dueDate);          
                if (event.status && event.result) {  
                  $.each(event.result, function () {                
                     // for each result, apply it to template and append generated markup
                     // to the results table body.
                     $("#resultTableRowTemplate" ).tmpl(this).appendTo( "#searchResults tbody" );
                  }
                 );            
                } else {
                   alert(event.message);
                }
            }, {escape:true});
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("check update correct");
        
        $(function () {
          
          $('.datacel').click(function() {
            var allData = $(this).parent().parent().first().text();
            console.log("allData value is>>>>",allData);
            //alert(allData);
          });
          
          $('input:not(#button)').click(function () {
            t = $(this).attr('id');
        
            text = $('.time' + t).text();
            //alert(text);
          });
        
          $('#button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var trs = $('table tr');
            var values = trs.first().find('td');
           // var idr = $('#Idvalue').val();
           // console.log("idr value",idr);
            var values1 = $('table tr td :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
             
             console.log('\nId::::',$(this).attr('id'));
             return $(this).attr('id');
             
             /*return $(this).closest('tr').find('td').text() + "=="
             + values.eq($(this).parent().index()).text();
             console.log("id val",$(this).parent().find('td').eq(1).text());
             return $(this).closest('td').find('td').eq(1).text()+
             values.eq($(this).parent().intex()).text();*/
                
            }).get(); 
                
            console.log("values1",values1);
            getUpdate(values1);
            console.log("after passing vales1", values1);
            console.log("values1",values1);
            return values1;

            });
        
            //alert(values1);
            //console.log("values1",values1);
            //return values1;           
            //getUpdate(values1);
        
          });    
    
        function getUpdate(values1) { 
        
            var taskRecord = JSON.stringify(values1);
            console.log("data type taskRecord",typeof(taskRecord));
            console.log("task record value is>>>",taskRecord);
            var ownerIdValue = $('[id$="owner_lkid"]').val();
            console.log("data type ownerIdValue",typeof(ownerIdValue));
            //var ownerIdValue = document.getElementById('{!$Component.owner}').value;
            console.log("ownerId value is >>>>",ownerIdValue);
            console.log("values1 >>>>",values1);
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.TaskOwnerUpdate.updateTask}',
                       ownerIdValue, taskRecord, function(result, event){  
                              
            if (event.status) {  
            
                     callaction();   
            } else {
               
            }
            }, {escape:true});            
         }
    </script> 

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

for any response appriciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all this code works perfect to my requirement feel free to use/refer it.
controller:

```
//Remote function using updated the owner of the task
public class TaskOwnerUpdate {

    public String dueDate { get; set; }
    public Set<Id> selectedTaskIdSet {get; set;}
    String ownerIdValue {get; set;}
    String selectedColumnValue {get; set;}
    public static List<Task> taskList { get; set;}
    public TaskOwnerUpdate() { } // empty constructor
    public List<Task>selectedtaskList {get; set;}

    public Task getOwnerIdTask() {

        return [SELECT  OwnerId FROM TASK LIMIT 1];
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static List<Task> getTask (String dueDate) {

        system.debug('dueDate value is------>'+dueDate);
        List<String> stList = dueDate.split('"');
        system.debug('stList value---->'+stList);
        List<String>s1 = stList[0].split(',');
        system.debug('stList[0] value is---->'+stList[0]);
        system.debug('stList[1] value is---->'+stList[1]);
        List<String> splitList = stList[1].split('/');
        system.debug('splitList value is---->'+splitList);
        String dueDate1 = splitList[2]+'-'+splitList[0]+'-'+splitList[1]; 
        taskList = [SELECT Id, Subject, Priority, Status, ActivityDate, Owner.Name, OwnerId 
                   FROM Task WHERE ActivityDate >= :Date.valueOf(dueDate1)];
        system.debug('taskList- value is------>'+taskList);
        return taskList;        

    }

    @RemoteAction 
    public static List<Task> updateTask(String ownerIdValue, String selectedColumnValue ) {

        system.debug('OwnerId value is----->'+ownerIdValue);
        system.debug('selectedColumnValue value is---->'+selectedColumnValue);

        List<Task> updatedTaskList = new List<Task>();


        Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<String> deserializeStringList = (List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(selectedColumnValue, List<String>.class);

        system.debug('deserializeStringList value>>>>'+deserializeStringList);

        for (String strRecord : deserializeStringList) {

            Task taskRecord = new Task();
            taskRecord.Id = Id.valueOf(strRecord);
            taskRecord.OwnerId = Id.valueOf(ownerIdValue);
            updatedTaskList.add(taskRecord);
        } 

        if (updatedTaskList.size() > 0) {
            Update updatedTaskList;
        }
         return updatedTaskList;

    }

}
```

page:

```
<apex:page controller="TaskOwnerUpdate" applyHtmlTag="true">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"/>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Task Ownership Update"/>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Tasks">
     <!---- Section to draw search field for account-------> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Tasks" columns="2">
                <!----<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >----->
                    <apex:inputText value="{!dueDate}" size="10" id="demo" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false)" label="DueDate"></apex:inputText>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!OwnerIdTask.OwnerId}" id="owner" label="Owner"></apex:inputField>
                <!----</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>------>               
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <center>
                <button onclick="getTask();return false;">Get Task</button>            
                <button id="button">Update</button> 
            </center>             

            <apex:actionFunction name="callaction" oncomplete="getTask()" reRender="output"/>

         <!-- result section for showing matching accounts ------->
            <apex:outputPanel id="output">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Matching Tasks !" columns="1">
                <!-- 
                Created Empty table using the CSS styles of visualforce pageBlockTable 
                This gives same look and feel ------>

                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="searchResults" class="list ">
                        <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
                        <thead class="rich-table-thead">
                            <tr class="headerRow ">
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow"><input type="checkbox" id="chkbx1" class="chek1"/></th> 
                                <!--<th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Id</th>---->
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Subject</th>
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Priority</th>
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">Status</th>
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">ActivityDate</th>
                                <th colspan="1" scope="col" class="headerRow">OwnerName</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <!-- table body left empty for populating via row template using jquery-------> 
                        <tbody />
                    </table>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>  

        <script id="resultTableRowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <tr onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " class="dataRow even  first">
                <td class="datacel"><input type = "checkbox" id="${Id}" class="chek2"/></td>
                <!---<td class="Idvalue">${Id}</td>------>
                <td class="datacell">${Subject}</td>
                <td class="dataCell">${Priority}</td>
                <td class="dataCell">${Status}</td>
                <td class="date">${ActivityDate}</td>
                <td class="datacell">${Owner.Name}</td>      
            </tr>
        </script>

      </apex:pageBlock> 

         <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready( function() {
                console.log('check box select');
                select();
                $('.chek2').live('click', function() {
                    console.log('click function');
                    if ( $('.chek2').length == $('.chek2:checked').length ) {
                        $('.chek1').attr('checked', true); 
                    }   
                    else {
                        $('.chek1').attr('checked', false); 
                    }       
                });
            });

            //select is followingly

            function select() {
                var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
                console.log(checkboxes);

                $("[id*='chkbx1']").change(function() {
                       console.log('click::::');
                       if($(this).attr('checked') == true) {
                           $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
                       } else {
                           $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
                       }
                });  
                    console.log('click function is here');
            }

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //var ms = valueof(${ActivityDate});
            //console.log('ms', document.getElementById('date'));

            function myFunction(ms) {

                console.log('ms', ms);               
                var dtnum = new Date(ms); 
                var dat = (dtnum).getDate();
                var dtmon = (dtnum).getMonth()+1;    
                    if (dtmon < 10) {
                        dtmon = '0'+dtmon;
                    }
                var dtyear = (dtnum).getFullYear();
                var fulldate = dtmon + '/'+dat + '/' + dtyear; 
                console.log('fulldate is::::', fulldate);
                //console.log($("#date").val());
                //$("#date").val() = fulldate;            
                return fulldate;           
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // if you are inside some component
            // use jquery nonConflict
            // var t$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            console.log("check call correct");
            //var dt = Date.new Instance(document.getElementById('datecell'));
            //console.log('dt value', dt);
            function getTask() {

                var dueDate = $('[id$=":demo"]').val();//$('#demo').val();
                console.log("check data",dueDate);
                 //console.log('ms', document.getElementById('date'));
                // clear previous results, if any
                $("#searchResults tbody").html('');

                // The Spring-11 gift from force.com. Javascript remoting fires here
                // Please note "abhinav" if my org wide namespace prefix
                // testremotingcontroller is the Apex controller
                // searchAccounts is Apex Controller method demarcated with @RemoteAction annotation.
                // DEPRECATED -     abhinav.testremotingcontroller.searchAccounts( accountName, ...) 
                // NEW - summer'12 approach for calling'

                dueDate = JSON.stringify(dueDate);
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.TaskOwnerUpdate.getTask}',
                               dueDate, function(result, event){  
                               console.log("due date",dueDate);          
                    if (event.status && event.result) {  
                        console.log("::::::::check::::::::",event.result);

                        $.each(event.result, function( index, value ) { 

                            event.result[index].ActivityDate = myFunction(value.ActivityDate);                            
                            console.log('event.result[index].ActivityDate',event.result[index].ActivityDate);
                            $("#resultTableRowTemplate" ).tmpl(this).appendTo( "#searchResults tbody" );
                        });            
                    } else {
                       alert(event.message);
                    }
                }, {escape:true});
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("check update correct");

            $(function () {

                $('.datacel').click(function() {
                    var allData = $(this).parent().parent().first().text();
                    console.log("allData value is>>>>",allData);
                    //alert(allData);
                 });

                 $('input:not(#button)').click(function () {
                     t = $(this).attr('id');

                     text = $('.time' + t).text();
                     //alert(text);
                 });

                 $('#button').click(function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var trs = $('table tr');
                     var values = trs.first().find('td');
                     // var idr = $('#Idvalue').val();
                     // console.log("idr value",idr);       
                     var values1 = $('table tr td :checkbox:checked').map(function () {

                         console.log('values1 is following',values1);
                         console.log('\nId::::',$(this).attr('id'));
                         if ($(this).attr('id') != "chkbx1") {
                             return $(this).attr('id');
                         }
                     }).get(); 

                     console.log("values1",values1);
                     getUpdate(values1);
                     console.log("after passing vales1", values1);
                     console.log("values1",values1);
                     return values1;
                 });

                //alert(values1);
                //console.log("values1",values1);
                //return values1;           
                //getUpdate(values1);

              });    

            function getUpdate(values1) { 

                 var taskRecord = JSON.stringify(values1);
                 console.log("data type taskRecord",typeof(taskRecord));
                 console.log("task record value is>>>",taskRecord);
                 var ownerIdValue = $('[id$="owner_lkid"]').val();
                 console.log("data type ownerIdValue",typeof(ownerIdValue));
                 //var ownerIdValue = document.getElementById('{!$Component.owner}').value;
                 console.log("ownerId value is >>>>",ownerIdValue);
                 console.log("values1 >>>>",values1);
                 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.TaskOwnerUpdate.updateTask}',
                           ownerIdValue, taskRecord, function(result, event) {  

                     if (event.status) {  

                         callaction();   
                     } else {

                     }
                 }, {escape:true});            
             }
        </script> 

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

thanks, Raj

Answer (score 1):

The library [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is perfect for this. It lets you manipulate data as time data, and lets you format it in a number of different ways.

Using it, if you were to add an identifier to the element in question:

```html
<td id="activityDateCell" class="datecell"></td>
```

then you could run this javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  var activityDate = "${activityDate}";
  
  activityDate = moment(activityDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  
  $("#activityDateCell").append(activityDate);
  
</script>
```

Comment: got error on inspect element section TaskOwnerUpdatePage:113 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
and visual page is not provide the datatable.

Comment: You will need to import the moment.js library into your page.

So you'd need to download and include the moment.js library in your project and just include this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="${pathToFolderWithMoment.jsIn}/moment.js"></script>

in your page, above the script that I have suggested above.